# Getting io.grpc.StatusException from Firebase Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting this runtime exception a lot from Firestore. Below I have attached the stacktrace. I am using:

> com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1

```
 Caused by io.grpc.StatusException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable. 
at io.grpc.Status.asException(SourceFile:534) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzs.zza(SourceFile:98) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.zzd.zza(SourceFile:122)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.zzab.zza(SourceFile:321) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.zzf.zza(SourceFile:236) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.f.zzo.zza(SourceFile:6527) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.f.zzv.zzb(SourceFile:2089) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.f.zza$zzb.zza(SourceFile:73)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzm$1.onMessage(SourceFile:77) 
at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onMessage(SourceFile:36) 
at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onMessage(SourceFile:36) 
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(SourceFile:498)
at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(SourceFile:37) 
at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SourceFile:123) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152) 
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zza$zza.run(SourceFile:190) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I am not sure but I think I am getting this exception when I am calling ***task.getResult()*** inside onComplete callback of ***firestore.Collection()*** method.

Comment: what is operation you are trying to run? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/handling_datastore_errors#handling-datastore-timeouts

Comment: I am calling task.getResult() inside onComplete callback of firestore.Collection() method

Comment: are you exceeding usage limit ? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas you might want to rethink of your collection size

Comment: I don't think we are exceeding our writes/second or concurrent connections. Also the size of the document is less than 5kb

Answer (score -1):

Try to check this. If you didn't login into you APP, try set read as TRUE
[Firestore Rule Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd0Kl.jpg)

```html
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Am I getting this error because I haven't checked  task.isSuccessful() before calling task.getResult()?

Comment: hey @saurabhlahoti, have you found an answer?

Comment: yes .. it was happening due to multiple firebase projects being in my app and i wasn't providing the correct project ID for accessing the specific firestore